# Is there any way to compress a multivariate discrete probability density function less than exponential time using its symmetry property?

Tags: combinatorics, probability-distributions

Suppose we are given a N-variate discrete probability density function $p$. We are interested in compressing this function via using its symmetry properties. The density function takes the same values for any index permutations.

For example, Let $N=3$ and the density takes values on the domain $\{0,1,2\}$. Then, we are only interested in the following numbers, rather than the whole density which has $3^3$ elements:

$a1=p(0,1,1)+p(1,1,0)+p(1,0,1)$

$a2=p(2,1,1)+p(1,1,2)+p(1,2,1)$

$a3=p(0,0,1)+p(1,0,0)+p(0,1,0)$

$a4=p(2,2,1)+p(1,2,2)+p(2,1,2)$

$a5=p(2,2,0)+p(0,2,2)+p(2,0,2)$

$a6=p(0,0,2)+p(2,0,0)+p(0,2,0)$

$a7=p(0,0,0)$

$a8=p(1,1,1)$

$a9=p(2,2,2)$

$a10=p(1,0,2)+p(2,1,0)+p(0,1,2)+p(1,2,0)+p(2,0,1)+p(0,2,1)$

The compression ratio is $10/27$.

The importance of this question is to be able to store only the necessary information of the density function if it exhibits a symmetry property as described.

> Assume that we have a $1000$-variate density function on the same sample space. Then we cannot even think about analyzing the whole p.d.f. but if it has the symmetry property, then we need to store only around $10^6$ elements, which is feasible. The problem is how to compress the density having $3^{1000}$ element in humanly normal time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are trying to figure out how many different pmf entries you need to save given $N$ variables with $K$ values. The formula is the following:

$$ \sum_{r=1}^K\left(\array{K\\r}\right)\left(\array{N-1\\r-1}\right), $$

where $\left(\array{N\\m}\right) \equiv \frac{N!}{m!(N-m)!}$ for $0\le m \le N$, 0 otherwise.

You can verify it is true for $N=3, K=3$.

The justification for the fomula is the following:

- There are $\left(\array{K\\r}\right)$ ways to pick $r$ different values out of $K$ different values in total to be assigned for $pmf$ data points;
- For each set of values chosen, the $N$ variables need to be assigned one of the $r$ values. Let value $i$ be assigned to $x_i$ number of variables, $1\le i \le r$. Then $\sum_{i=1}^rx_i=N$, and $1\le x_i$. Each $(x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_r)$ uniquely determins a $pmf$ data point since all permutations are considered the same. The number of positive solutions to the equation $\sum_{i=1}^rx_i=N$ is $\left(\array{N-1\\r-1}\right)$.

Implicit in the above derivation, you can have a way to save the $pmf$ data points in a systematic way when it comes to programming/coding. It is a compression in the sense that all you need to save are values of $a_i$ (in a deterministic order), and their indices can be derived given $N$ and $K$ hence do not need to be saved.

---

A bit pseudo codes per request, but rough (lots of missing details)(note my $a_i$ is not a sum, it is any of the value of permuted entries):

**Creating and saving the $a_i$s**

```
for r=1, ..., K
  loops for picking r-tuple
    loop for picking one equation solution
      access data (e.g.) a_i=p(0, 2, 1, 0) (N=4,K=3)
      you also have the map (#0=2, #1=1, #2=1, #3=0) -> i (deterministic)
```

**To read e.g. $p(0, 2, 1, 0)$**

```
1. mapping from (0, 2, 1, 0) -> (#0=2, #1=1, #2=1, #3=0)
2. => r= 3, chosen values for the r (0, 1, 2), and eq solution is (2, 1, 1)
3. mapping from {r=3, v=(0, 1, 2) solution=(2, 1, 1)} -> i is deterministic given N, K
4. read a_i
```

Comment: I am looking for an algorithm to compress the joint density to a lower dimensional density without requiring exponential time as the title of the question states. Just assume the marginals of the joint density and convolve them with each other. The resulting density is a lower dimensional density approximation and can be done in linear time.. In case of i.i.d. random variables, this approximation is exact. In case of non i.i.d. random variable, one can use the approximation that I mentioned. So I am interested in being able to do it.

Comment: For pmf with symmetry properties, the above algorithm provides a way to sample the pmf with $N^K$ operations, i.e. polynomial time & storage. If that is not what you need, I guess I might not be understanding your intention properly.

Comment: can you give a pseudo-code for general N- and K? It seems I overlooked to your answer when I saw just the formula about how many ways there were to calculate the the total number of $a_k$s.

Comment: updated the answer

Comment: The algorithm (granted, lots of details left out) gives you: $N^K$ time & space to save the $pmf$. The formula gives you nearly O(1) time to reconstruct the deterministic map to access the $pmf$. I am not sure about its being O(1) because you might need a loop to figure out the ordinal position on some occasions.

Comment: Upvoted. Algorithm seems not useful to me.

Comment: Well, @SeyhmusGüngören, I sort of think the formula gives exactly what you need plus flexibility in sampling (i.e. instead of taking $a_i = \sum p(i_1, i_2, \cdots)$, the formula enables you to use $a_i$= p(one mapped entry index) $\times$ (count of symmetric entires), or even better: $a_i=\left( \sum_{k\ samples}p(some\ entry\ indices)\right)$ $\\ \times (count\ of\ symmetric\ entires)/k$). You just need to adapt the formula I gave and fill in all the missing details.

Comment: BTW, I think the key is to fully understand how the formula is derived/reached, and then you can adapt it to your need.

Answer (score 1):

If $X_1,\ldots,X_N$ are random variables taking values in $\{1,\ldots, K\}$ and having the joint pmf $p(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$, then your description corresponds to the pmf of $(S_1,\ldots,S_{K-1})$, where  $S_{k}:=\sum_{i=1}^N 1\{X_i=k\}$.

Comment: $K-1$ total random variables? I didnt understand how one gets $a_1,...,a_{10}$ from $S_1,S_2$..

Comment: Compute the pmf of $(S_1,\ldots,S_{K-1})$. For $(s_1,\ldots,s_{K-1})$ with $z\equiv\sum_{k=1}^{K-1}s_k\le N$,
$$
Pr(S_1=s_1,\ldots,S_{k-1}=s_{k-1})=\frac{N!}{s_1!\cdots s_{k-1}!(N-z)!}p(\underbrace{1,\ldots,1}_{s_1},\underbrace{2,\ldots,2}_{s_2},\ldots).
$$

Comment: I still have problems to understand whats going on. So for my example in the question, you have only $S_1$ and $S_2$, each taking values on $\{1,2,3\}$? Then there are altogether $9$ different cases right? where is the tenth? could you please give more details in the answer? for example just solve the given example?

Comment: Each $S_k$, $k=1,\ldots,K$, takes values in $\{0,\ldots,N\}$. Also $S_K=N-\sum_{k=1}^{K-1}S_k$ and so can be omitted.

Comment: In your example $a_1$ corresponds to $Pr(S_1=1,S_2=2)=3p(1,2,2)$.

Comment: Not clear to me. what is $p(S_1=0,S_2=0)=kp(?,?)$ and $p(S_1=3,S_2=3)=kp(1,1,1,2,2,2)$. They not in the format $p(x_1,x_2,x_3)$. Besides, I got in total $2^4$ possible combinations.

Comment: $Pr(S_1=0,S_2=0)=p(3,3,3)$ and $Pr(S_1=3,S_2=3)=0$ (in your example). In general the support of $(S_1,\ldots,S_{K-1})$ is $$\left\{x\in \{0,\ldots, N\}^{K-1}:\sum x_k\le N\right\}.$$

For example, with $N=K=3$, the size of the latter is 10.

Comment: I tried to verify. Your formula in your comment is incomplete. For example it doesnt explain $P(S_1=1,S_2=1)$ or $P(S_1=1,S_2=0)$. I can get them however, so by replacing $3$ for the case of $0$ and if there is a missing index, then I fill it with $3$ as well. So I get $P(S_1=1,S_2=1)=6p(1,2,3)$ and $P(S_1=1,S_2=0)=p(1,3,3)$. So in this way, as long as I understood, I will get the correct value if the symmetry condition on the joint density holds right? Because if it doesnt hold, I will need to get $P(S_1=1,S_2=1)=p(0,1,2)+p(0,2,1)+...+p(2,1,0)$, instead of $P(S_1=1,S_2=1)=6p(0,1,2)$ right?

Comment: +1. Thank you very much.